# Linq Aggregate on object and List

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I do this query with NHibernate:

```
    var test = _session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Estimation))
                .SetFetchMode("EstimationItems", FetchMode.Eager)
                .List();
```

An "Estimation" can have several "EstimationItems" (Quantity, Price and ProductId)

I'd like a list of "Estimation" with these constraints :

1. One line by "Estimation" code on the picture (ex : 2011/0001 and 2011/0003)
2. By estimation (means on each line) the number of "EstimationItems"
3. By Estimation (means on each line) the total price (Quantity * Price) for each "EstimationItems"

I hope the structure will be clearer with the picture below.

Thanks,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, Tuple<int,decimal>> dico = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<int,decimal>>();
foreach (var itemEstimation in test)
{
    Estimation estimation = (Estimation)itemEstimation;
    if (dico.ContainsKey(estimation.Code) == false)
    {
        decimal total = 0;
        foreach (var item in estimation.EstimationItems)
        {
            EstimationItem estimationItem = (EstimationItem)item;
            total += item.Price * item.Quantity;
        }
        dico.Add(estimation.Code, new Tuple<int, decimal>(estimation.EstimationItems.Sum(x => x.Quantity), total));
    }
}

List<TestingUI> finalResult = new List<TestingUI>();
foreach (var item in dico)
{
    Tuple<int, decimal> result;
    dico.TryGetValue(item.Key, out result);
    finalResult.Add(new TestingUI() { Code = item.Key, Quantity = result.Item1, Total = result.Item2 }); 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? It seems to me you're only taking in account the first occurence of a code. And also, is TestingUI.Quantity supposed to contain the number of estimations with a said code or the total number of items contained by all estimations with a said code?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a proposition:

```
var stats =
    from estimation in test
    group estimation by estimation.code into gestimation
    let allItems = gestimation.SelectMany(x => x.EstimationItems)
    select new 
        {
            Code = gestimation.Key,
            ItemNumber = allItems.Count(),
            TotalPrice = allItems.Sum(item => item.Price * item.Quantity)
        };
```

Now this creates an anonymous type with the three properties you wanted (code of the estimation, number of items for this estimation code, and total price of the items for this estimation code).

You can adapt it to specific needs. Just bear in mind that allItems is a `IEnumerable<EtimationItem>` containing all the EstimationItem belonging to a Estimation with the same code.

If you want to use this object outside the scope of the method creating it, which you can't do with anonymous types, then you should create a class to hold these values.

Corrected proposition:
proposition:

```
var stats =
    (from est in test.Cast<Estimation>()
    group est by est.code into gEst
    let allItems = gEst.SelectMany(est => est.EstimationItems).Cast<EstimationItem>()
    select new TestingUI
        {
            Code = gEst.Key,
            Quantity = gEst.Count(),
            Total = gEst.Sum(item => item.Price * item.Quantity)
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: test is implicit and I receive this error :
"Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Collections.IList'.  'GroupBy' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'estimation'"

Comment: I don't have a working nhibernate instance here, but isn't there a generic List<Estimation>() method available you could use instead of List()? This shoud work, but if not, try 'from estimation in test.Cast<Estimation>()'.

Comment: See me answer, it's not perfect but it's working. Improvements are welcome

Comment: added a different solution based on yours. Maybe you can replace "from est in test.Cast<Estimation>()" with "from Estimation est in test"